# Firebase Notifications not showing up on installed PWA

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm using firebase notifications (FCM campaigns) to send push notifications to a react PWA. Once the user installs the PWA on their phone, these notifications show up for a day or two, and then stop showing up. The behavior is similar on both android and iOS devices.

The notifications don't show up at all when the app is in the background, which is the expected behavior. I want the notifications to show up every day at a specific time, especially when the user does not have the app open.

Here is a screenshot of how my notifications are set up in firebase:
[image]

I have a firebase-messaging-sw (service worker) in my code (in the **public** directory), which has the following code:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: '/favicon.png',
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Could someone please help me out with why the notifications don't show up after the first day or two and what I should change to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track by adding the PWA to your home screen and using a background service worker to fire off notifications. I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but be sure to prompt users to enable them and register/update the worker as needed.

Basic example for reactjs:

In some file (ex. firebase.js):

```js
const getOrRegisterServiceWorker = () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    return window.navigator.serviceWorker
      .getRegistration('/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope')
      .then((serviceWorker) => {
        if (serviceWorker) return serviceWorker;
        return window.navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
          scope: '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope',
        });
      });
  }
};
```

```js
const getFBToken = (setTokenFound) => {
    try {
      getOrRegisterServiceWorker()
        .then((serviceWorker) => {
          if (serviceWorker) {
            return getToken(messaging, {
               vapidKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FB_VAPID_KEY, 
               serviceWorker
            }).then((currentToken) => {
              if (currentToken) {
                setTokenFound(true);
              } else {
                setTokenFound(false);
              }
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
          }
        });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

In the relevant component file:

```js
const AppComponent = ({}) => {

  const [displayNotif, setDisplayNotif] = useState(false);
  const [isTokenFound, setTokenFound] = useState(false);

  function reqNotifPerm() {
    try {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
        if (result === "granted") {
          try {
            setTokenFound(true);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (!(isTokenFound)) {
        setDisplayNotif(true);
      } else if (isTokenFound) {
        setDisplayNotif(false);
        getFBToken(setTokenFound);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },[isTokenFound]);

  return (
    //...
    {displayNotif && <div onClick={() => { reqNotifPerm() }}>
      {"Enable Notifications"}
    </div>}
    //...
  );
};
```

Let me know if you have any further questions, and be sure to mark this as the accepted answer if it helps.